# The Game Restarts It Self After The Game Is Over

Tags: javascript

```js
let pokemonHealth
let pokemonEnergy
let pokemonChoice
let pokemon
let attack1
let attack2
let attack3
let playAgain
let opponent
let opponentHealth
let opponentRandomNumber
let opponentAttackRandomNumber
let opponentDamageRandomNumber
//
function restart() {
  opponentHealth = 100
  pokemonHealth = 100
  pokemonEnergy = 100
  playAgain = confirm("Would you like to play")
  if (playAgain == true) {
    choices()
  } else {
    thanksForPlaying()
  }
}
//
restart()
//
function choices() {
  pokemonChoice = prompt("Which pokemon do you choose?\n1 for Bulbasaur\n2 for Charmander\n3 for Squirtle")
  //
  opponentRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1
  if (opponentRandomNumber == 1) {
    opponent = "Pansear"
  } else if (opponentRandomNumber == 2) {
    opponent = "Pansage"
  } else if (opponentRandomNumber == 3) {
    opponent = "Panpour"
  }
  //
  if (pokemonChoice == 1) {
    pokemon = "Bulbasaur"
    attack1 = "Razor Leaf"
    attack2 = "Vine Whip"
    attack3 = "Leech Seed"
    game()
  } else if (pokemonChoice == 2) {
    pokemon = "Charmander"
    attack1 = "Ember"
    attack2 = "Flame Tail"
    attack3 = "Draw In"
    game()
  } else if (pokemonChoice == 3) {
    pokemon = "Squirtle"
    attack1 = "Bubble Beam"
    attack2 = "Water Gun"
    attack3 = "Withdraw"
    game()
  } else {
    alert("Invalid input, please try agian")
    restart()
  }
}
//
function game() {
  while (opponentHealth <= 0) {
    win()
  }
  while (pokemonHealth <= 0) {
    lose()
  }
  attackChoice = prompt("Which attack do you want to use?\n1." + attack1 + "\n2." + attack2 + "\n3." + attack3 + "\nType 1, 2 or 3")
  if (attackChoice == 1) {
    pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy -= 5
    attackOne()
  } else if (attackChoice == 2) {
    pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy -= 15
    attackTwo()
  } else if (attackChoice == 3) {
    pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy -= 15
    attackThree()
  } else if (attackChoice == 1 || attackChoice == 2 || attackChoice == 3) {
    alert("Not enough energy")
  } else {
    alert(pokemon + " has missed\n(invalid input)")
    opponentAttack()
  }
}
//
function attackOne() {
  alert(pokemon + " used " + attack1)
  pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy += 10
  let attack1RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
  opponentHealth = opponentHealth -= attack1RN
  alert(opponent + " has " + opponentHealth + "hp left!")
  opponentAttack()
}
//
function attackTwo() {
  alert(pokemon + " used " + attack2)
  pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy += 10
  let attack2RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 8
  opponentHealth = opponentHealth -= attack2RN
  alert(opponent + " has " + opponentHealth + "hp left!")
  opponentAttack()
}
//
function attackThree() {
  alert(pokemon + " used " + attack3)
  pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy += 10
  let attack3RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
  pokemonHealth = pokemonHealth += attack3RN
  alert(pokemon + " now has " + pokemonHealth + "hp remaining")
  opponentAttack()
}
//
function opponentAttack() {
  while (opponentHealth <= 0) {
    win()
  }
  while (pokemonHealth <= 0) {
    lose()
  }
  opponentAttackRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
  if (opponentAttackRandomNumber == 1 || opponentAttackRandomNumber == 2 || opponentAttackRandomNumber == 3) {
    opponentDamageRandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
    alert(opponent + " has used quick attack")
    pokemonHealth = pokemonHealth -= opponentDamageRandomNumber1
    alert(pokemon + " has " + pokemonHealth + "hp left!")
  } else if (opponentAttackRandomNumber == 4 || opponentAttackRandomNumber == 5) {
    opponentDamageRandomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 8
    alert(opponent + " has used tackle")
    pokemonHealth = pokemonHealth -= opponentDamageRandomNumber2
    alert(pokemon + " has " + pokemonHealth + "hp left!")
  } else if (opponentAttackRandomNumber == 6) {
    opponentDamageRandomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
    alert(opponent + " has used heal")
    opponentHealth = opponentHealth += opponentDamageRandomNumber3
    alert(opponent + " has " + opponentHealth + "hp left!")
  }
  game()
}
//
function win(){
  alert(opponent + " has fainted\nYOU WIN")
  restart()
}
//
function lose(){
  alert(pokemon + " has fainted\nYOU LOSE")
  restart()
}
//
function thanksForPlaying(){
  alert("Thank you for playing pokemon game\n By Spencer")
}
```

Theres A Function Being Called Even Though Its Not Being Called

I Think Its A Function Being Called But I Can't Find Nor Can My Friend

This Is Not My Code, Just A Friends

I call the function game to stat the attack sequence however even after the function thankYouForPlaying has been finished it calls the function game again.

Comment: just wanted to say; please do not destroy my friend's reputation over my bad code, I know there are better ways, and I have way too many variables and functions. I should just use an array. don't downvote pls..................................................................................................................................... -thanks, Spencer ................................................................................................................................................... p.s. I'm too lazy to make an account

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say it re-runs after the `thanksforplaying()` function.  Because when I run it and click Cancel instead of OK for the first prompt, it does not re-run.  If you actually play the game once, whether you win or lose, it's calling `reset()` which will restart the game.

Comment: if you cancel the confirm prompt before playing then it will stop, if you play and then cancel, it calls thankYouForPlaying( ) and then calls game( ). I do not want it to call game but IDK how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to cancel the `game()` function and the `opponentAttack()` function by calling `return;` immediatelly after `win();`/`lose();`. Then you could uncomment the `restart()` function inside your `function win()` and `function lose()` like so ↓↓

I have set opponent's health bar to `5` to make the fight less bloody :D and easier to test

```js
(function () {
    //
    let pokemonHealth
    let pokemonEnergy
    let pokemonChoice
    let pokemon
    let attack1
    let attack2
    let attack3
    let playAgain
    let opponent
    let opponentHealth
    let opponentRandomNumber
    let opponentAttackRandomNumber
    let opponentDamageRandomNumber
    //
    function restart() {
        opponentHealth = 5
        pokemonHealth = 100
        pokemonEnergy = 100
        playAgain = confirm("Would you like to play")
        if (playAgain == true) {
            choices()
        } else {
            thanksForPlaying()
        }
    }
    //
    restart()
    //
    function choices() {
        pokemonChoice = prompt("Which pokemon do you choose?\n1 for Bulbasaur\n2 for Charmander\n3 for Squirtle")
        //
        opponentRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1
        if (opponentRandomNumber == 1) {
            opponent = "Pansear"
        } else if (opponentRandomNumber == 2) {
            opponent = "Pansage"
        } else if (opponentRandomNumber == 3) {
            opponent = "Panpour"
        }
        //
        if (pokemonChoice == 1) {
            pokemon = "Bulbasaur"
            attack1 = "Razor Leaf"
            attack2 = "Vine Whip"
            attack3 = "Leech Seed"
            game()
        } else if (pokemonChoice == 2) {
            pokemon = "Charmander"
            attack1 = "Ember"
            attack2 = "Flame Tail"
            attack3 = "Draw In"
            game()
        } else if (pokemonChoice == 3) {
            pokemon = "Squirtle"
            attack1 = "Bubble Beam"
            attack2 = "Water Gun"
            attack3 = "Withdraw"
            game()
        } else {
            alert("Invalid input, please try agian")
            restart()
        }
    }
    //
    function game() {
        while (opponentHealth <= 0) {
            win(); return true;
        }
        while (pokemonHealth <= 0) {
            lose(); return true;
        }
        attackChoice = prompt("Which attack do you want to use?\n1." + attack1 + "\n2." + attack2 + "\n3." + attack3 + "\nType 1, 2 or 3")
        if (attackChoice == 1) {
            pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy -= 5
            attackOne()
        } else if (attackChoice == 2) {
            pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy -= 15
            attackTwo()
        } else if (attackChoice == 3) {
            pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy -= 15
            attackThree()
        } else if (attackChoice == 1 || attackChoice == 2 || attackChoice == 3) {
            alert("Not enough energy")
        } else {
            alert(pokemon + " has missed\n(invalid input)")
            opponentAttack()
        }
    }
    //
    function attackOne() {
        alert(pokemon + " used " + attack1)
        pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy += 10
        let attack1RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
        opponentHealth = opponentHealth -= attack1RN
        alert(opponent + " has " + opponentHealth + "hp left!")
        opponentAttack()
    }
    //
    function attackTwo() {
        alert(pokemon + " used " + attack2)
        pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy += 10
        let attack2RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 8
        opponentHealth = opponentHealth -= attack2RN
        alert(opponent + " has " + opponentHealth + "hp left!")
        opponentAttack()
    }
    //
    function attackThree() {
        alert(pokemon + " used " + attack3)
        pokemonEnergy = pokemonEnergy += 10
        let attack3RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
        pokemonHealth = pokemonHealth += attack3RN
        alert(pokemon + " now has " + pokemonHealth + "hp remaining")
        opponentAttack()
    }
    //
    function opponentAttack() {
        while (opponentHealth <= 0) {
            win(); return true;
        }
        while (pokemonHealth <= 0) {
            lose(); return true;
        }
        opponentAttackRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
        if (opponentAttackRandomNumber == 1 || opponentAttackRandomNumber == 2 || opponentAttackRandomNumber == 3) {
            opponentDamageRandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
            alert(opponent + " has used quick attack")
            pokemonHealth = pokemonHealth -= opponentDamageRandomNumber1
            alert(pokemon + " has " + pokemonHealth + "hp left!")
        } else if (opponentAttackRandomNumber == 4 || opponentAttackRandomNumber == 5) {
            opponentDamageRandomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 8
            alert(opponent + " has used tackle")
            pokemonHealth = pokemonHealth -= opponentDamageRandomNumber2
            alert(pokemon + " has " + pokemonHealth + "hp left!")
        } else if (opponentAttackRandomNumber == 6) {
            opponentDamageRandomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
            alert(opponent + " has used heal")
            opponentHealth = opponentHealth += opponentDamageRandomNumber3
            alert(opponent + " has " + opponentHealth + "hp left!")
        }
        game()
    }
    //
    function win() {
        alert(opponent + " has fainted\nYOU WIN");
        restart();
    }
    //
    function lose() {
        alert(pokemon + " has fainted\nYOU LOSE");
        restart();
    }
    //
    function thanksForPlaying() {
        alert("Thank you for playing pokemon game\n By Spencer")
    }
})()
```